# How to Upload video to server from iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, video, uploading

```
-(IBAction)uploadToServer :(id)sender
{
    NSString *str1=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"intro.mp4"];
    NSLog(@"str1=%@",str1);

    NSString *escapedUrlString = [str1 stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"escapedUrlString=%@",escapedUrlString);

    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:escapedUrlString];
    NSLog(@"videoURL=%@",videoURL);

    NSData *newdata = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:escapedUrlString];
    webdata=[NSData dataWithData:newdata];
    NSLog(@"webData = %@",webdata);
   [self post:webdata];
    }

- (void)post:(NSData *)fileData
{

    NSData *videoData = fileData;
    NSString *urlString = @"http://rompio.com/web_service/web.php?method=upload_video&user_id=4";

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\".mp4\"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:videoData]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"returnString=== %@", returnString);
}
```

Comment: Write you code properly so It will easy to understandable to others. Any way what is problem you are getting while uploading ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047607/uploading-file-only-transmits-few-byes-fo-data-ios/20069694#20069694

Comment: In this Code.WebData is coming Null.Also Video is not successfully getting posted to the server.

Comment: Hi Mr.Bhumeshwer Katre.The problem is that video is not getting posted to the Server..

Comment: Hello Dilip.Thanks for URL refrence.But in that code they have used AFHTTPRequestOperation .But where i can find this file for IOS7 compatible.

Comment: In that link i have given the answer which use the AFNetworking and its compatible with iOS7. Just check it out.

Comment: @user2754190 : Is `newdata` null ?

Comment: Yes New data and WebData..Both are coming empty

Comment: AFNetworking will help

Comment: @user2754190: what is `videoURL` ? remote url or local file's url ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy to do with the AFNetworking library and you can also use it to track the progress of the video upload. You can download AFNetworking library from [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking).

And for configuring AFnetworking please refer this [Link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/30445).

And this code will used to send the video on server

```
 NSString *videoURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myVideo" ofType:@"mov"];
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: videoURL]];

AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.example.com"]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@"/videoupload.php" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData)
{
    [formData appendPartWithFileData:videoData name:@"file" fileName:@"myVideo.mov" mimeType:@"video/quicktime"];
}];



AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest: request];

[operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten,long long totalBytesWritten,long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
 {

     NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);

 }];

[operation  setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {NSLog(@"Video Uploaded Successfully");}
                                  failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {NSLog(@"Error : %@",  operation.responseString);}];


[operation start];
```

Comment: I download the file for AF networking.But there is not such file name consist of AFHTTPClient

Comment: There is some changes in the new AFNetworking update please refer this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502673/afnetworking-afhttpclient-class

Comment: [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten,long long totalBytesWritten,long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite)         Now i am getting error in just this line. Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(NSInteger, long long, long long)' to parameter of type 'void (^)(NSUInteger, long long, long long)'

Comment: Comment those code its just for tracking the progress. And i will look into it for the error.

Comment: Or you have to download `AFHTTPRequestOperation` explicitly and add it in your project. Bcoz `AFHTTPRequestOperation` is not part of the afnetworking

Comment: Hello Dilip. I am using this web service.http://rompio.com/web_service/web.php?method=upload_video&user_id=4   And i am using the code above which you suggest me.But i am not getting success.Can you please try and upload any video.and help me

Comment: Ok Thanks …I am waiting friend..As this is very urgent to me ..I am trying for this last three days .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41515/discussion-between-user2754190-and-dilip)

Answer (score 0):

Store selected video URL in some variable :

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)info {
    if ([mediaType isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeMovie]) {
        selectedVideoURL = info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    }
}
```

For latest version of `AFNetworking`, below code is used.

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictParams1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dictParams1 setObject:userID forKey:"userID"];
[dictParams1 setObject:otherparam forKey: "otherparam_Key"];

NSLog(@"REQUEST URL : ------------------ %@", API_URL);
NSLog(@"PARAMETERS : ------------------ %@", dictParams1);

NSString *strFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld.mov", [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:APIAddFeedVideo parameters:dictParams1 constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {

    [formData appendPartWithFileURL:selectedVideoURL name:@"videofile" fileName:strFileName mimeType:@"video/mov" error:nil]; // video/quicktime //video/mp4
} error:nil];

AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask;
uploadTask = [manager uploadTaskWithStreamedRequest:request progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {

    // This is not called back on the main queue.
    // You are responsible for dispatching to the main queue for UI updates

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //Update the progress view
        //[progressView setProgress:uploadProgress.fractionCompleted];
    });
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
          NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"VIDEO UPLOAD RESPONSE : %@ %@", response, responseObject);

    }
}];

[uploadTask resume];
```